# Error when executing Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to Oracle, i am developing a query to my project. For me it seems to be everything is OK but when executing the query oracle is giving the error "ORA-00905: missing keyword".

Her is my query::

```
SELECT DISTINCT ba.uuid AS uuid
     , COUNT(*) over() AS rowcount 
FROM basicaddress ba 
WHERE ba.postalcode='143456' 
   OR ba.lastname LIKE '%143456%' 
   OR ba.city LIKE '%143456%'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ba.postalcode='143456' THEN ba.postalcode, ba.uuid END
       , CASE WHEN ba.lastname LIKE '%143456%' THEN ba.lastname, ba.uuid END
       , CASE WHEN ba.city LIKE '%143456%' THEN ba.city, ba.uuid 
                                           ELSE ba.postalcode,ba.uuid END 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ba.postalcode='143456' THEN ba.postalcode END DESC
       , CASE WHEN ba.lastname LIKE '%143456%' THEN ba.lastname END ASC
       , CASE WHEN ba.city LIKE '%143456%' THEN ba.city ASC 
                                           ELSE ba.postalcode END DESC
```

What Key word i am missing ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your `CASE` statements

```
CASE 
  WHEN ba.postalcode='143456' 
  THEN ba.postalcode, ba.uuid  <-- here. You can return value of only one column
END;
```

You have to decide between `ba.postalcode` and  `ba.uuid`. Or, if you want to see values of both columns in your final result set concatenate them using [||](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators003.htm#i997789) operator or [CONCAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions033.htm#i77004) function using implicit or explicit type conversion.

Comment: thank you very much for your Answer, when i dont supply ba.uuid then oracle saying "No GROUP BY expression".

Comment: As I've noticed, `uuid` is present in every result of `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` clause, you can move `uuid` column in front of the `CASE` statement: `group by uuid, CASE WHEN .... THEN`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you intended to use an `ELSE` clause in your `CASE` expression, perhaps like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ba.uuid AS uuid
     , COUNT(*) AS rowcount
FROM basicaddress ba  
WHERE ba.postalcode='143456'
   OR ba.lastname LIKE '%143456%'
   OR ba.city LIKE '%143456%' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ba.postalcode='143456' 
              THEN ba.postalcode
              ELSE ba.uuid END
       , CASE WHEN ba.lastname LIKE '%143456%' 
              THEN ba.lastname
              ELSE ba.uuid END
       , CASE WHEN ba.city LIKE '%143456%' 
              THEN ba.city
              ELSE ba.postalcode,ba.uuid END
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ba.postalcode='143456'
              THEN ba.postalcode END DESC
       , CASE WHEN ba.lastname LIKE '%143456%' 
              THEN ba.lastname END ASC
       , CASE WHEN ba.city LIKE '%143456%'
              THEN ba.city ASC
              ELSE ba.postalcode END DESC
```

You also do not need the `over()` clause on your `COUNT()` function.  Also, I refomratted your query in a way to hopefully make the syntax easier to follow, and corrected what I thought was a syntax error in one of your `CASE` expressions.  Note that to be safe, your should always provide an `ELSE` condition.  I'll leave that part to you.